# How to make domain disappear from the search results without access to the site or to Google Search Console?

Tags: seo, domains, url-removal

One of my friends just lost his domain. I don't really know the reason why, but he can't ever get it back.

His website is re-created to a new domain. Without access to the old domain, we can't even set up appropriate HTTP statuses like 410 or 301.  We can no longer access the Google Search Console to make things quicker.

The old domain returns an error now but is still showing up in the search results before the new domain even on brand keywords. Is there any way of speeding up the de-indexing of the old domain?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> To remove search results of Old Domain

If you're looking to remove search results from Google, please use the URL Removal Tool found here: https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/removals

You have to submit all the URLs of the domain, so that they will be temporarily removed from SERP. As you state, the lost domain is inaccessible and is not pointing to your content or a working webpage, you should have no problem.

`Notes: If you have lost the domain and the pages are still live, you will have to fix that`

> To rank your New Domain

Do the SEO Optimization on pages, point your old backlinks if possible to your new domain, submit the sitemap and wait for Google to index and rank your pages :)

Comment: Great, I didn't know there is a tool even if I can't verify the website.

Comment: That tool is part of Google Search Console.   You say you can't access that, so I'm not sure how this answer is going to help you.   Even if you could get to that tool, it only works for one page at a time, not for the entire site.  I could see using it if you had a dozen pages on your site, but not if you had a hundred.

Comment: Using GoogleSearch Console, you can request for any URL not available on the web or following the noindex directive to be removed from the Search Results for Google. Yes, it works for one page at a time, the OP has to do this manually since he wants his new site to rank for those keywords. If there is any other possible way @StephenOstermiller kindly let me know!

Comment: Also for OP to get his new website rank more faster, I have included to update the backlinks he has access to.

Comment: I didn't realize the tool works with pages not on your own domain.   So they could get into search console with their new domain and use it for the old domain pages.

Comment: Yes, exactly. Glad to help!

Comment: "As you state, the lost domain is giving a 404" - Well, strictly speaking the OP stated: "The old domain returns an error" - this could be a DNS error, not necessarily a 404.

Comment: @MrWhite In majority of the cases, when you lose the domain, it will either give a 404 or a parked page or DNS. I am rephrasing it to be accurate. If the page is not available for any reason, it can be requested for removal.